# KeyListener stop working with Action or Mouse Listenter?

Tags: java, keyboard, key, keylistener, keyevent

I want to add KeyListener to get input through keyboard, so i add keyListener and implements its methods, but when i run that and press any key it works but in console it write something like this:

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
at Calculator.keyReleased(Calculator.java:520)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

after this keylistener is working fine but when i click on any button it stopped working, i press keys but nothing happens.
my code:

```
 @Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    try{

        switch (e.getKeyCode())

{
case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0:
case KeyEvent.VK_0:
     num0();
     break;
case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1:
case KeyEvent.VK_1:
     num1();
     break;
case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2:
case KeyEvent.VK_2:
    num2();
     break;
case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3:
case KeyEvent.VK_3:
    num3();
     break;
case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4:
case KeyEvent.VK_4:
    num4();
     break;
case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD5:
case KeyEvent.VK_5:
    num5();
     break;
case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD6:
case KeyEvent.VK_6:
    num6();
     break;
case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD7:
case KeyEvent.VK_7:
    num7();
     break;
case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8:
case KeyEvent.VK_8:
    num8();
     break;
case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9:
case KeyEvent.VK_9:
    num9();
     break;
case KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE:
     back();
     break;
case KeyEvent.VK_DELETE:
     clear();
     break;
case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
    equals();
     break;
case KeyEvent.VK_ADD:
    bAdd();
    break;
case KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL:
    bDot();
    break;
case KeyEvent.VK_MULTIPLY:
      bMul();
     break;
case KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT:
    bSub();
   break;
case KeyEvent.VK_DIVIDE:
    bDiv();
   break;
default:

}
}
catch(UnsupportedOperationException ex){}

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");// line 520
}
```

Comment: If you want your code to be fixed, why showing only an error message instead?

Comment: For any of us to effectively help you we need the stack trace shown above and the code generating it.

Answer (score 1):

your program threw an exception

```
at Calculator.keyReleased(Calculator.java:520)
```

it also threw an exception of the following type:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
```

So, It seems that you're calling a routine on line 520 of your `Calculator.java` file that is Not supported yet.

If you could post the method where it's breaking, and then mark the line that it breaks on, we can help you further.

Comment: here my code of keylistener methods:

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    
     try{
      
      switch (e.getKeyCode())
     
    {
    //my cases
    default:
     
    }
    }
   catch(UnsupportedOperationException ex){}
    
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");//line 520
    }

Comment: @SudhirYadav  edit your question.  your code will be better formatted that way